# What are the most efficient ways of obtaining polymer in single player on the island?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

I'm playing single player on The Island and need large quantities of polymer but I'm at a loss on how to efficiently obtain large quantities. At first my limiting factor was chitin for cementing paste but I have solved that by locating and marking caves on my map. Now it seems like my biggest limiting factor is obsidian.

My current strategy has been using the Awesome Teleporters mod to the blue obelisk and to the tek cave with my ankylosaurus and harvest there. At this point however, both locations have all but completely run out of obsidian and more doesn't seem to be generating.

Are there either any other methods of gathering obsidian, getting it to respawn, or obtaining polymer another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Farm organic polymer - it acts as normal one, except it spoils after 30mins.
Find Kairuku  around north-west part of Island and hit it with Wooden Club for best results.
If you need "large amounts" for some reason - in singleplayer you could increase Harvest - quantity of items gained in settings. But organic polymer should be enough.

Comment: With a wooden club to knock them unconscious? If so so is it for taming or why not kill them? Also I need hundreds of polymer to upgrade my armor. Will this be able to get my enough?

Comment: @Himitsu_no_Yami kill them with anything you want, but "mine them" with Wooden Club. It will be enough. Also young Kairuku gives more polymer and prime meat.

Comment: Thanks for that, it just seemed weird that the club would be used but I understand now.